# Access all products for a particular collection in collection.liquid - liquid

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have some header menus as main menu which have other child menus(submenus). I am sufficiently accessing all products collection individually for a particular submenu selection but I want to access all products for a particular collection if "All" (submenu in each menu) is clicked.

Structure is as following:
-Seasonings (Menu)
-- All (submenu - which is to display all products from this collection)
-- Pure seasonings (submenu)
-- Signature seasonings (submenu)
-- Whole seasonings(submenu)

-Drawings
--All (submenu - which is to display all products from this collection)
--Monthly (submenu)
--Annually (submenu)

I am writing like this in header.liquid

```
{% if link.url == '/collections/seasonings' %}
    {% for product in link.object.products %}
        {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but this is not seems okay.

thanks in  advance....

Comment: I want to access it in collection.liquid file

Comment: Has been link in navigation admin defined by selecting collection in a select or has it been typed manually?

Comment: Links and children already been defined in navigation. I tried collection to access in page.liquid but these are not accessing there.

Comment: Let me be more clear, there is a difference when you define link in navigation. Between select and paste a link, that's actually my question, did you paste link or did you select collection in select? If you pasted link object is not available.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access an object from links array, you must have used the link selector in Shopify nav admin and not paste directly a link in text input (fig below).

[image: Shopify navigation admin]

There is a simple way to check that with your code :

```
{% for link in linklists['my-nav'].links %}
    {% if link.type == 'collection' %}
        Collection object is available (via link.object)
    {% elsif link.type == 'http_link' %}
        Link has been pasted and collection object is not available/recognized.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out @Alice Girard.

Comment: May you please help me out for one situation ? Actually I want to concatenate some products and make it similar to collection. In this regard I tried concat, append, join and split but unable to concatenating products.  like:  {%assign pross = collections['meat-easy-indie-bowls'].products | concat: collections["paneer-easy-indie-bowls"].products  %}

Comment: Would you mind to open a new post for this question?